# Update CSV file on AWS using PHP

Tags: php, html

Please I need help on updating my CSV file used to store form data. It worked perfectly when the file was on my local server but as soon as i uploaded to AWS, it stopped populating the form data into the CSV file.

Here's my current code:

```
<form action="processform.php" method="get" name="miform">
<div id="level_03b">
<div id="level_03bmain">
<div id="level_03b01">
    <input class="textboxstyle_01" type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name" />*<br />
    <input class="textboxstyle_01" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" name="email" />*
</div>
<div id="level_03b02">
    <input class="textboxstyle_01" type="text" placeholder="COMPANY NAME" name="companyName" />*<br />
    <input class="textboxstyle_01" type="text" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" name="phoneNumber" />*
</div>
<div id="level_03b03">
<p><textarea class="textboxstyle_02" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" rows="20" cols="40"></textarea><br />Kindly supply info such as qty and interested products</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="level_03c"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitBTTN" /></div>
</form>
```

**processform.php**

```
<?php
$home = 'index.html';
$name = $_GET['name'];
$keys = array('name','email');
$csv_line = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
    array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
}
$fname = 'bulk.csv';
$csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
$fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
$fcontent = $csv_line;
fwrite($fcon, $fcontent);
fclose($fcon);
header('Location: '.$home);
?>
```

Comment: Check the success of fwrite ... ?  Y'know, permissions 'n stuff ...

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Im not very familiar with php though, so how do I check the success of fwrite as you recommend? Thanks for helping with the codes on my question as well. its actually my very first question on here